# Unable to connect to atlas MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, minikube

I'm running a soringboot application in minikube. But it's not able to connect to MongoDB cluster which is on atlas. Can someone help me with this issue? I'm able to connect from my local but not from minikube pod. I've minikube cluster with docker driver

Comment: Hello @Healthy Bowl Can you add an error output for connection problems from Minikube?